# Unable to get nearest latitude and longitude from Sql Server Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to apply the radius on nearest location. SQL query is working before `HAVING` clause. If I execute whole query then its giving error is :

> "Invalid column name 'dist'."

My Sql query is:

```
SELECT name, latitude, longitude, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(30.901) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * 
cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(75.8573) ) + sin( radians(30.901) ) * 
sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS dist
FROM res HAVING dist <= 25 ORDER BY dist ASC
```

I tried same above query. But that is half working. If I execute without `HAVING` clause then its working. Otherwise giving me an error:

> "Invalid column name 'dist'".

Comment: Having is used to filter groups of data. You don't have a group by here or any aggregates. I suspect this is as simple as changing your HAVING to a WHERE

Comment: That, and you can't filter on expressions created in the `select` of the same (sub)query. Why did you expect either of these things to work? That they do not are quite basic SQL facts.

Comment: @underscore_d what do you mean? You can do that with no problem using an alias. select name + '_' as x from sys.tables order by x The order by cannot be an expression, there is no limitation that the column being aliased cannot be a derived column.

Comment: @SeanLange You are `order`ing. I was talking about **filtering** with `where` or `having`.

Comment: @underscore_d ahh yes I was talking about ordering since that was the focus but yes you would have to subquery this or something to use it in the where clause.

Comment: @SeanLange or far superior, a CTE ;-)

Comment: @underscore_d a cte is syntactical sugar for the same thing. But yes I tend to prefer a cte over a subquery for this type of thing too. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subquery to define the columns, then select from that.

See if this works for you.

```
Select name, latitude, longitude, dist
From (
SELECT name, latitude, longitude, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(30.901) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * 
cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(75.8573) ) + sin( radians(30.901) ) * 
sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS dist
FROM res ) A
 WHERE dist <= 25 ORDER BY dist ASC
```

Comment: There is no group by. The HAVING is not going to work here.

Comment: "not working" is not a problem description. Why not? What was the error?

Comment: I was hung up on the `Having` clause, but you don't need it. Give that a try.

Comment: I tried multiple times having but getting error.Now just replaced having with where then its working

Answer (score 1):

having is for groupped data. use where instead.

use this :

```
SELECT      *
FROM        (
                SELECT name, latitude, longitude, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(30.901) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * 
                cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(75.8573) ) + sin( radians(30.901) ) * 
                sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS dist
                FROM res
            ) myResult 
WHERE myResult.dist <= 25 
ORDER BY myResult.dist ASC
```